# Как удалять объекты внутри радиуса взырыва?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Настроил взрыв в юнити, но не могу сделать удаление объектов внутри радиуса взрыва. Как прописать функцию Destroy в блоке определения объектов внутри радиуса чтобы эти объекты удалялись?

```
public void Explode()
{
    Collider[] overlappedColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, Radius);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < overlappedColliders.Length; i++)
    {
        Rigidbody rigidbody = overlappedColliders[i].attachedRigidbody;
        if(rigidbody)
        {
            rigidbody.AddExplosionForce(Force, transform.position, Radius, 1f);

            Explosion explosion = rigidbody.GetComponent<Explosion>();
            if(explosion)
            {
                if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, rigidbody.position) < Radius)
                {
                    Destroy(explosion.gameObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

public void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Explosion")
    {
        Explode();
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Instantiate(ExplosionEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}

private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, Radius);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй использовать Destroy(collision.gameObject)

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).